# Why isEqual: does not work for a property UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, if-statement, uibutton

I have got a problem:
I have set up a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *buttonX;
```

Also I have a method to create a button:

```
-(void)createChooseButton : (UIButton *) button
{
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];

    if ([button isEqual:self.buttonX]) {
        NSLog(@"Hello");
        [button setTitle:@"X" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/3, self.view.frame.size.height*2/3);
    }

    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

When I call this method from viewDidLoad, it does not work, but if I don't use If statement (with isEqual) everything is ok.
Please could you help me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: because you are creating this button again,   button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];, why you are creating a new button here?

Comment: I create a button only once in this method createChooseButton.

Comment: then how you are calling this method, before creating a button ?

Comment: i understand , but from where you are calling this "createChooseButton" method, and what argument you are passing for button?

Comment: 1. first I create a property UIButton *buttonX;
2. then I describe how this button should be created in my method createChooseButton : (UIButton *) button
3. then i call my method : [createChooseButton:self.buttonX]

Comment: i call it from viewdidload, for example. the problem is if i will not use if statement in my method which should check if I call buttonX, then everything works properly. I guess the problem is in isEqual: statement which does not see that "button isEqual:self.button"

Comment: isEqual will not work here, because you have two pointer here one point to button & second to buttonX. if you need to check the button , give a tag property to buttonX in didload & then check it in  createChooseButton method.

Comment: thank you! using a tag is a good idea. now everything works properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isEqual will not work here, because you have two pointer here one point to button & second to buttonX. if you need to check the button , give a tag property to buttonX in didload & then check it in createChooseButton method.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the`buttonX` in first place it's nil.
You have to`alloc` it and then call the method.

you should call

```
_buttonX = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

and then call

```
[createChooseButton:self.buttonX]
```

don't call **buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect** in the method